# What are the supported git url formats?

Tags: git, github, ssh

Git accepts a lot of different url formats (e.g. ssh, http, https etc). Are there any specifications/official docs where I can find the supported git url formats?

I wrote a [git url parser](https://github.com/IonicaBizau/node-git-url-parse) and I want to be sure that what it's done there is correct.

[Here, on YonderGit](http://jeetworks.org/yondergit-simplified-git-remote-repository-management/), I found the list below. It is not complete since `https://<token>:x-oauth-basic@host.xz/path/to/repo.git` is not there.

> ### Secure Shell Transport Protocol
>
> - `ssh://user@host.xz:port/path/to/repo.git/`
> - `ssh://user@host.xz/path/to/repo.git/`
> - `ssh://host.xz:port/path/to/repo.git/`
> - `ssh://host.xz/path/to/repo.git/`
> - `ssh://user@host.xz/path/to/repo.git/`
> - `ssh://host.xz/path/to/repo.git/`
> - `ssh://user@host.xz/~user/path/to/repo.git/`
> - `ssh://host.xz/~user/path/to/repo.git/`
> - `ssh://user@host.xz/~/path/to/repo.git`
> - `ssh://host.xz/~/path/to/repo.git`
> - `user@host.xz:/path/to/repo.git/`
> - `host.xz:/path/to/repo.git/`
> - `user@host.xz:~user/path/to/repo.git/`
> - `host.xz:~user/path/to/repo.git/`
> - `user@host.xz:path/to/repo.git`
> - `host.xz:path/to/repo.git`
> - `rsync://host.xz/path/to/repo.git/`
>
> #### Git Transport Protocol
>
> - `git://host.xz/path/to/repo.git/`
> - `git://host.xz/~user/path/to/repo.git/`
>
> #### HTTP/S Transport Protocol
>
> - `http://host.xz/path/to/repo.git/`
> - `https://host.xz/path/to/repo.git/`
>
> #### Local (Filesystem) Transport Protocol
>
> - `/path/to/repo.git/`
> - `path/to/repo.git/`
> - `~/path/to/repo.git`
> - `file:///path/to/repo.git/`
> - `file://~/path/to/repo.git/`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can see what git is prepared to parse in [`urlmatch.h`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/77bd3ea9f54f1584147b594abc04c26ca516d987/urlmatch.h) and [`urlmatch.c`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/77bd3ea9f54f1584147b594abc04c26ca516d987/urlmatch.c).
That is used by [`t0110-urlmatch-normalization.sh`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/77bd3ea9f54f1584147b594abc04c26ca516d987/t/t0110-urlmatch-normalization.sh), which illustrates the full list of possible url tested by git.

[`url.c`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/77bd3ea9f54f1584147b594abc04c26ca516d987/url.c) does mention:

> The set of valid URL schemes, as per STD66 (RFC3986) is '`[A-Za-z][A-Za-z0-9+.-]*`'.
>   But use sightly looser check of '`[A-Za-z0-9][A-Za-z0-9+.-]*`' because earlier version of check used '`[A-Za-z0-9]+`' so not to break any remote helpers.

Comment: I agree, s̶o̶m̶e̶t̶i̶m̶e̶s̶  often checking the source code is the best documentation. :) Thanks!

Comment: @IonicăBizău yes, I suspect https://github.com/git/git/blob/master/t/t0110-urlmatch-normalization.sh will be the most up-to-date git url list for some time.

Comment: That's also very useful!