# Canonical formatting of repo/branch/commit references

Tags: git

I wonder if there's a commonly agreed upon format for git references to specify not only git repos (as discussed [in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31801271/what-are-the-supported-git-url-formats)) but that also includes branch, tag or commit hash specifications.

Consider I wanted to notify someone about my latest experiments and point them over to `https://github.com/user/repo.git` commit `abcdef0` that, just for reference, happens to be in branch `experiment-32`.

I'd be tempted to state that like

```
https://github.com/user/repo.git experiment-32 abcdef0
```

Ideally it'd be some format that could be used for `git fetch` and `git checkout` directly, similar what e.g. `gerrit` provides in its [Download popup](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vObdQ.png) or [mercurial](https://www.mercurial-scm.org/) provides with the `$url#$hash` format but that's absolutely not necessary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no one single format. `pip`, for example, [uses](https://pip.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/pip_install/#vcs-support) rather complex coined URLs with some parameters (commit ID, branch name or tag) written with `@`-sign, some (subdirectory) added in the query part and some (name and version) added with `#`-mark.

But the format is `pip`-specific and is far from being the universal format.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, although I was hoping there would be more ;). The lack thereof might be a hint, though.

Comment: Well, sometimes "No" is the answer, sorry. :-)

Comment: Yes :) (which is too short to be posted on its own)